# Android project using java and C++ together

Tags: java, android, c++

Anybody have one example of a android project using a same time C++ and Java together, for example, one normal android project build on eclipse and in there add a cpp class and using this cpp class on java class...

say I have a class Foo on C++

```
class Foo{
...
}
```

and I have a class MyActivity on Java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
...
}
```

how to i instance the Foo class on MyActivity class?...

thanks a lot for all.

Comment: @matheszabi yes I need the android ndk, and I already have it, I wanted a example of a simple project using C++ and Java together rather on eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to make a .so of you c++ classes with build_ndk.sh

On the C++ side you have to declare your JNI methods

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_org_your_ackage_someFunction(JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj)
{}
```

On the java side

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    // Load Native Libary
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("your_lib_name");
    }

    public native void someFunction();
}
```

Then use the function as you would do in java.

You should take a look at this nice [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial)

Comment: You can do it with the "External tools configurations" by putting the location of the build_ndk.sh in the "Location" field of the "Main" tab

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to learn how to use the NDK, look at the documentation and samples in your NDK directory.

I would recommend starting with the `hello-jni` sample which is very easy to understand. It shows how to call C/C++ methods from Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of Android NDK examples under `path/to/<android-ndk-folder>/samples`. 
There is also a lot of helpful info in the `docs` folder, and on the [official site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html).